# How to specify the schemalocation in a generated wsdl

Tags: soap, jax-ws

When I generate a wsdl with

```
myservice?wsdl
```

Imports have no schemaLocation

```
<xs:import namespace="http://mynamespace" />
```

How do I get scemaLocation included?

```
<xs:import namespace="http://mynamespace" schemaLocation="myxsd.xsd"/>
```

I can't find any information on this, can someone put me on to something? Do I have to go through a binding file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [@XmlSchema](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) annotation, which is set in package-info.java file. Responsible for schemaLocation attribute is field [location](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html#location--), which was introduced in JAXB2.1.